# how to iterate complex json string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

we have this json data

```
{
 "class 1":
    [
        {"student_name":"ABC"},
        {"student_name":"BDC"}
    ],
 "class 2":
    [
        {"student_name":"BBB"},
        {"student_name":"ADS"}
    ]
}
```

we are using ejs as view in our express js application, we want output in html something like this
**Class 1**

- ABC
- BDC

**Class 2**

- BBB
- ADS

it was simple doing this in php using foreach($array as $key=>$value) but how can we do this in json string using javascript

right now only this i could think of

```
for(var i = 0;i<students.length;i++)
{
    %><%= students[i]['student_name'] %><%
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Enumerating_all_properties_of_an_object

Comment: http://www.embeddedjs.com/  I highly suggest you take the time to do the research yourself, they have similar things right on the front page as examples.

Comment: the question appears "too broad" unless you specify what HTML you tried or what EJS syntax you tried.

Comment: @prasun added code please check

Answer (score 1):

since you're dealing with an Object you can simply iterate over it as the commenters have linked/said.

Doing a `for loop` as below gives the incrementing variable the current object value so styling/markup is made simple, then the nested arrays work in a similar fashion.

```
<% var data = {
    "class 1": [
            {"student_name":"John"},
            {"student_name":"Harry"}
    ],
    "class 2": [
            {"student_name":"Kelly"},
            {"student_name":"Melanie"}
    ]
}
%>
<% for (x in data) {%>
    <h3><%- x %></h3>
    <ul>
    <% for (n in data[x]) {%>
        <li><%- data[x][n].student_name %></li>
    <% } %>
    </ul>
<% } %>
```